# PHP cURL POST request - File corrupted during upload

Tags: php, curl, redmine

I'm trying to upload files to Redmine using the following PHP code.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url)
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',
    'X-Redmine-API-Key: ' . $apiKey));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);

$data = array('file' => '@' . $filePath);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$token = curl_exec($curl);
```

This request returns a valid upload token but the file is corrupted during upload. Trying to upload, for example, an empty .txt file results in an uploaded overwritten .txt file now containing the following lines.

> ------------------------------dde946a683ac
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file";
>   filename="/var/www/wp-content/uploads/redmine_uploads/emptyTextFile.txt"
>   Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>
> ------------------------------dde946a683ac--

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out. Modifying my code to

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url)
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',
    'X-Redmine-API-Key: ' . $apiKey));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$file = fopen($filePath, 'r');
$size = filesize($filePath);
$filedata = fread($file,$size);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $filedata);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILE, $file);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $size);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$token = curl_exec($curl);
```

yields the desired file upload.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a name value in your `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` array.

```
$data = array('name' => 'SomeName', 'file' => '@' . realpath($filePath));
```

As an aside, you [no longer need](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55635) `CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER`.

Comment: Excluding `CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER` and editing 
`$data = array('name' => 'emptyTextFile', 'file' => '@' . $filePath);` 
still leads to a corrupted file now containing the lines 

------------------------------a943ac000d23
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

emptyTextFile
------------------------------a943ac000d23
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="/var/www/wp-content/uploads/redmine_uploads/emptyTextFile.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------------------------------a943ac000d23--